# 'Unused argument' error message for trying to produce a correlation matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to produce a correlation matrix (and later a correlation plot) using the ESS9 dataset from https://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/data/download.html?r=9

The variables that I'm using are ordinally scaled, but also have numeric labels attached to them.

I start by subsetting the relevant variables:

```
ess2 = ess %>%
  subset(select = c('polintr', 'trstprl', 'imbgeco', 'imwbcnt', 'imueclt'))
```

Then, I recode all of those variables to 'as.numeric':

```
ess2$polintr = as.numeric(ess2$polintr)
ess2$trstprl = as.numeric(ess2$trstprl)
ess2$imbgeco = as.numeric(ess2$imbgeco)
ess2$imwbcnt = as.numeric(ess2$imwbcnt)
ess2$imueclt = as.numeric(ess2$imueclt)
```

Now I produce a correlation matrix with the following command:

```
correlation_data = cor(select(ess2, polintr, trstprl, imbgeco, imwbcnt, imuelct), 
                       use = 'pairwise.complete')
```

But I end up getting an error message of 'unused arguments' in the select command...
When I just try to calculate the correlation coefficient of just two variables, it works perfectly fine.
Anybody that can help me out here?

Comment: It's unusual that you are using a combination of base (`subset`) and `dplyr` (`select` and `%>%`). I'm not sure why you're getting that error - does it still show up if you run it outside of the `cor` call? What does `select(ess2, polintr, trstprl, imbgeco, imwbcnt, imuelct)` give? If so, maybe you have another package with a `select` function, try `dplyr::select(ess2, polintr, trstprl, imbgeco, imwbcnt, imuelct)`.

Comment: But also, when you define `ess2`, it only has those columns. I'm not sure why you're bothering to `select` them again. `cor(ess2, use = 'pairwise.complete')` should work.

Comment: Lastly, if you want to convert all columns to numeric, I'd suggest simplifying your code to `ess2 = ess %>% select(polintr, trstprl, imbgeco, imwbcnt, imueclt) %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))`. (Though if you do have another package masking `select`, you'll still need to specify `dplyr::select` here.)